# Running ghostscript in Python using subprocess not working

Tags: python, subprocess, ghostscript

Okay, here's a link to my input.pdf file if someone would like to try making subprocess.Popen work with ghostscript to convert this pdf file to a txt file, I've tried everything I can think of based on your answers so far.

[Link to input.pdf file](https://app.box.com/s/3f35fg4tr3aho4r7c3x39k5ycuf8z1wf)

Again, executing ghostscript from the command line directly works fine and this is what I'm getting via cmd line:

```
C:\Misc>gswin32c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sPageList=1- -sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=
    output.txt input.pdf
    GPL Ghostscript 9.21 (2017-03-16)
    Copyright (C) 2017 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
    This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
    Processing pages 1-.
    Page 1
    Page 2
    Page 3
    Page 4
    Page 5
```

However the following Python code is returning a non-zero exit status 1.  In subprocess.check_output(), I've removed the file name variables and put in the file name path(s) directly to make things more straightforward.

```
import subprocess, os

#path for ghostscript executable
gs_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.21\\bin'

# dir where pdfs are located
dir_name = 'C:\\Misc'

# pdf to extract text from
file_name = os.path.join(dir_name,'input.pdf')

# output text file name
outfile_name = os.path.join(dir_name,'output.txt')

os.chdir(dir_name)


subprocess.check_output(['gswin32c',
'-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sPageList=1-', 'sDEVICE=txtwrite',
'-sOUTPUTFILE=C:\\Misc\\output.txt',
'C:\\Misc\\input.pdf'])
```

The complete output from Python is (Anaconda Python 3.5):

```
runfile('I:/Downloads/0.data/help_pdf.py', wdir='I:/Downloads/0.data')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-0ba7dc571302>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('I:/Downloads/0.data/help_pdf.py', wdir='I:/Downloads/0.data')

  File "C:\Custom_Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 688, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Custom_Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "I:/Downloads/0.data/help_pdf.py", line 28, in <module>
    'C:\\Misc\\input.pdf'])

  File "C:\Custom_Programs\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Custom_Programs\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['gswin32c', '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sPageList=1-', 'sDEVICE=txtwrite', '-sOUTPUTFILE=C:\\Misc\\output.txt', 'C:\\Misc\\input.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Seems like it's having a problem with the input.pdf file path.

Comment: If ghostscript's usage were really what you say it is, it couldn't write to filenames with spaces. It *can* write to filenames with spaces. Thus, the claim that you can pass it two different filenames inside the same argument with a space separating them is obviously wrong.

Comment: Also, if the syntax were what you claimed, the documentation would be telling people to run `-sOutputFile='tiger.png tiger.eps'`, with quotes telling the shell to pass both filenames as part of a single element in the argv array. It doesn't.

Comment: `'sDEVICE='` needs to be `'-sDEVICE='`; the leading `-` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the upstream documentation. When it tells you:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
    -sOutputFile=tiger.png tiger.eps
```

`-sOutputFile=tiger.png` and `tiger.eps` are two separate arguments, and you need to be passing them in different array positions.

---

The following code has been successfully tested with your given `input.pdf` on MacOS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import subprocess, sys

gs = 'gswin32c' if (sys.platform == 'win32') else 'gs'
file_name = 'input.pdf'
outfile_name = 'output.txt'

subprocess.check_output([gs,
    '-dBATCH', '-dNOPAUSE', '-sPageList=1-', '-sDEVICE=txtwrite',
    '-sOUTPUTFILE=%s' % (outfile_name,), file_name])
```

Note that `-sDEVICE=` starts with a `-`, which wasn't the case previously.

Comment: I thought that might be the case and have tried specifying the output and input files as separate entries of the list, like so: subprocess.check_output(["gswin32c", '-ps2ascii', '-sPageList=1-',
'-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH', 'sDEVICE=txtwrite',
"-sOUTPUTFILE=C:\\Misc\\output.txt", "C:\\Misc\\input.pdf"],shell=True)             but that didn't work either.

Comment: With `shell=True` it won't. Leave that off.

Comment: There's also no point in the 'ps2ascii' switch. Once upon a time you could use the ps2ascii program (which is not the same as a command line switch) to extract text, but we've removed that program, nowadays you should (as you are) use the txtwrite device. But that doesn't take a switch named 'ps2ascii'.

Comment: Good lord, I probably wouldn't have caught that missing  '-' on sDEVICE in a million years.  Now it's working and thanks so much.